# Mathematical definition of wavefront in case of non-harmonic waves

Tags: waves, definition

What is the general **mathematical** definition of [wavefront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront)?

> Wavefront is the surface where, at fixed time, the **phase** is constant

But for **non-harmonic** waves we cannot talk about phase as the function $\phi(\vec{r},t)=\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}-\omega t+ \delta$, so what can be the mathematical way to define a wavefront in the case of a generic wavefunction $\xi (\vec{r},t)$ (not necessarily sinusoidal)?

Comment: The condition is then that the wavefunction $\xi$ itself is constant for a given time.

Comment: I don't think that's a very good general definition of a wavefront. To be honest, I don't think that a wavefront can be defined in a really strict way. One can probably construct extremely pathological cases of waves that won't allow any approximation by wavefronts, no matter what the definition is.

Comment: How exactly do you define a "non-harmonic wave"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A progressive wave is a function of space and time where the dependence on space and time can be modeled by a function of one variable, composed with an “argument” function, which combines space and time and describes the geometry of the wave. Wavefronts are the loci where the “argument” function is constant.

Let’s give a few examples.

### Plane wave

If $A(\vec r,t)$ is a plane wave of velocity $c$ propagating in the direction of unit vector $\vec u$, it can be expressed as $A(\vec r,t)=f(\vec r·\vec u-ct)$. What I call the “argument” function is the argument of $f$, namely $\vec r·\vec u-ct$. The wavefront is defined by $\vec r·\vec u-ct=\text{const.}$, which indeed is a plane (orthogonal to $\vec u$) moving at speed $c$.

### Spherical wave

If $B(\vec r,t)$ is a spherical wave of velocity $c$, the source of which is at $\vec r=\vec 0$, it can be expressed (e.g.) as $B(\vec r,t)=g(r-ct)/r$. The “argument” function here is $r-ct$ (not $1/r$, which only describes the amplitude decay in space). The wavefront is thus defined by $r-ct=\text{const.}$, which indeed is a sphere (centered on $\vec r=\vec 0$) of radius growing at speed $c$.

### Other waves

As long as the wave is progressive, in principle it can be put under the form $a(r)×f(w(\vec r,t))$ where $a$ describes the amplitude in space, $f$ is the wave form, and $w$ is the “argument” function describing the propagation.

---

As you can see, I made no hypothesis on the wave *form*. “Harmonic” refers to the form of $f$ or $g$ above, namely they must be sinusoidal functions, not to the front geometry. The latter, as any locus, is given by an equation like $w(\vec r,t)=\text{const.}$